# Core Animation profile in Instruments is nowhere to be found

Tags: iphone, xcode4, instruments, xcode-instruments

I want to debug my core animation code. However, the instruments profile doesn't exist, and it's not available in the library in instruments either.

I'm using Xcode 4. How do I install/access it and get it working?

Comment: What kind of app is it: Mac or iPhone? The Core Animation Instruments template is for iPhone only.

Comment: Sorry that i wasn't clear, I'm doing iPhone development

Comment: When you say "the instruments profile doesn't exist", do you mean that the Core Animation template is not available when you choose File > New in Instruments? If that's the case, all I can tell you is that it is available for me if I select All or Graphics under iOS.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Core animation profiling is only available from a device.  It won't show up if you're profiling the simulator.